# Using Electron with Python application

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, user-interface, electron

I am trying to make a cross platform desktop app based on Python.

I've been looking for Python GUI Frameworks such as PyQT, wxPython, tkinter, and kivy. However, none of them could provide a good look and feel for desktop GUI except for PyQT, but PyQT is quite expansive for commercial use, and I do not want to open my sources. In addition to that, making python GUI installable seems pretty hard that I fail to make installable program so many times. So I am now looking for something else which is Electron.

I've found that Electron's NodeJS can run python app using python-shell. Also, Electron is being used pretty well and has many famous products, so I thought it can be a good choice.

My concerns are, is it a good way of developing a cross platform desktop app in this way? Though I am familiar with Html, CSS and some JS, I am not familiar with NodeJS. But since this is kind of a work around, I am worrying this could make a lot of overhead or create bad user experience.

My python app contains quite a lot of mathmatical tasks. Not super heavy, but still kinda heavy using many regressions. Also using SQLite for internal database.

Of course, the best solution would probably be using NodeJs instead of running Python in NodeJs, but concerning the time to develop everything again in NodeJS, I thought this could be more practical. If this approach slows the program significantly, perhaps I have to find another way.

So in summary,

1. Is it a good idea to make a cross platform commercial app with quality using Electron and Python?
2. Does it affect the app's performance significantly?
3. If it is a bad idea, is there any alternative or recommendation?

Comment: It's really tiresome to find worthwhile questions closed by moderators.  What would it hurt to allow this conversation to evolve??